# Secure RTSP video stream in Flutter

Tags: flutter, vlc, rtsp, rtsp-server, srtp

I am trying to use secure vlc stream for my flutter app. I am using flutter_vlc_player package. Also the vlc itself doesn't support rtsps streams. Is there any solution for this that will work in both android and ios. Or is there any other package couldn't find any.

thanks in advance :)

I am also trying to find the compiled vlc files so it can help somehow.